# Set typedef that can be 2 different types

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, types, mergesort

I am trying to make a function that can receive a variable which can be a char or an int and for that I have to give the variable a type but I don't know what to put because I want it to be able to receive both.
My code is like this and i don't know what to put in the spot where is written 'IDK':

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int is_string = 0;
#define less(A,B) (!is_string ? ((A)<(B)) : (strcmp(A,B)<0))

void merge(IDK a[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    IDK aux[10000][20];
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = m+1; i > l; i--) aux[i-1] = a[i-1];
    for (j = m; j < r; j++) aux[r+m-j] = a[j+1];
    for (k = l; k <= r; k++){
        if (less(aux[j], aux[i])) a[k] = aux[j--];
        else a[k] = aux[i++];
    }
}

void mergesort(IDK a[], int l, int r) {
 int m = (r+l)/2;
 if (r <= l)
 return;
 mergesort(a, l, m);
 mergesort(a, m+1, r);
 merge(a, l, m, r);
}

int main(){
    mergesort(a,left,right);
}
```

I want the 'IDK' to be char when the variable `is_string`is 1, and int when else...
The goal is to use the function to sort words alphabetically or numbers (lowest to highest), the function just has to sort one type of object at a time, but I want it to be able to sort both types of objects so I don't have to repeat code.
I want to have a program that chooses (at runtime) what type it needs to sort.
Thanks

Comment: Use a `union` type.

Comment: Do you want it to be `char` or `char *`? `strcmp()` needs `char *`.

Comment: @Vasco Trancoso Vaz And where is there aux declared?

Comment: From your macro `less` I guess you want to compare numbers or strings. This will get more complicated because a `char[]` is either an array of single characters or *one* string of characters. In order to copy strings you would have to work with pointers or use `strcpy`. Do you want to use both variants (integer or string) in the same program or do you want to select one at compile time? Please [edit] your question to clarify this, don't use comments to answer.

Comment: @Bodo done, and it's exactly that, I want my algorithm to be able to sort strings at times and integers at other times

Comment: @VascoTrancosoVaz I still didn't understand yet how you want to choose between sorting numbers or strings. Do you want to compile one program that can sort numbers and a different progran that can sort strings or do you want to create one program that can choose at runtime between sorting numbers or strings?

Comment: Where do you want to define or allocate `aux` and what should be its size?

Answer (score 1):

The general approach of writing such functions in C is to declare a function that accepts a pointer of the type `void *` together with the number of elements in the passed array, the size of an object of the array element type and a comparison function similarly how the standard C function `qsort` is declared.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows such an approach.

The function `merge` can be written without allocating dynamically memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void merge( void *a, size_t m, size_t n, size_t size, int cmp( const void *, const void * ) )
{
    void *p = malloc( n * size );
    
    size_t i = 0, j = m;
    
    char *pos = p;
    
    while ( i < m && j < n )
    {
        if ( cmp( ( char * )a + j * size, ( char *)a + i * size ) < 0 )
        {
            memcpy( pos, ( char * )a + j * size, size );
            ++j;
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy( pos, ( char * )a + i * size, size );
            ++i;
        }
        
        pos += size;
    }
    
    if ( i <  m )
    {
        memcpy( pos, ( char * )a + i * size, ( m - i ) * size );
    }
    
    if ( j <  n )
    {
        memcpy( pos, ( char * )a + j * size, ( n - j ) * size );
    }
    
    memcpy( a, p, n * size );
    
    free( p );
}

void mergesort( void *a, size_t n, size_t size, int cmp( const void *, const void * ) )
{
    if ( n / 2 )
    {
        mergesort( a, n / 2, size, cmp );
        mergesort( ( char * )a + n / 2 * size, n - n / 2, size, cmp );
        merge( a, n / 2, n, size, cmp );
    }
}

int cmp_int( const void *p1, const void *p2 )
{
    int a = *( int * )p1;
    int b = *( int * )p2;
    
    return ( b < a ) - ( a < b );
}

int cmp_string( const void *p1, const void *p2 )
{
    return strcmp( *( const char * const * )p1, *( const char * const * )p2 );
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    const size_t N1 = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N1; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    mergesort( a, N1, sizeof( *a ), cmp_int );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N1; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    char * s[] = { "J", "I", "H", "G", "F", "E", "D", "C", "B", "A" };
    const size_t N2 = sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N2; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%s ", s[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    mergesort( s, N2, sizeof( *s ), cmp_string );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N2; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%s ", s[i] );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
J I H G F E D C B A 
A B C D E F G H I J
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, this is for a school project and my teacher says we can't reserve memory, nor use the malloc and memcpy functions, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @VascoTrancosoVaz The function merge can be written without dynamic memory allocation. That is you can merge partitions of an array in place. It seems you are using an auxiliary array aux. In fact this is a memory allocation

Comment: I am new to algorithms, i don't understand much, I just know we can't use the malloc and memcpy functions you use in your code. The aux is a global array yes, my teacher gave us guidelines to do it that way.

Comment: @VascoTrancosoVaz You should consult your teacher. Also you can search in the internet how yo merge two partitions of an array in place.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a `union`, but that won't work with your calls to `scanf` and `printf`. They expect a certain type of argument depending on the format modifier, in this case expecting an `int` or `int*` for modifier `"%d"`.

```
union IDK
{
    int int_val;
    char *string_val;
};
void merge(union IDK a[], int l, int m, int r);
```

What you read from the console is always a string. `scanf` can convert it to a number, if that's what you ask for with "%d". But it appears that what you really are looking for is a way to sort strings that may consist of digits. The easiest way to do that is to try to convert it using `strtol`.

There's another pitfall you should be aware of. `strcmp` compares the ASCII values of characters. This won't sort alphabetically, if that's what you're looking for.

Note that a generalized sorting function is usually implemented by passing it a `void*`, the number of elements, the size of those elements, and a function pointer to a comparison function. See `qsort` for an example.

Comment: The scanf and printf are there just for the sake of testing, when I put the sorting algorithm in my main project there won't be that problem, also I tried the union and the code keeps generating errors in the macros for some reason, any thoughts?

Comment: @VascoTrancosoVaz You can access the value of a union by the member names, eg `a.int_value`. Unions are usually inside a `struct` that also has some sort of information about what type of data is in the union. This is not a drop in replacement of code.